Transistor emmitor turning on without power from the collector
I am new to circuitry and I tried to follow a tutorial on how to make an and gate with transistors. I think this is what the circuit looks like, but I'm not that good with schematics:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Whenever I turn on the second switch, the LED turns on without power from the collector. I've tried to see if the first transistor is the problem, but the second one still turns on without it. I've done other tests and this seems to be normal. I used 2N2222A transistors for the circuit. Is this normal, and if so, should I use a different type of transistor?
(edit) I realized that I forgot to add resistors into the schematic. In real life I have what is now shown in the schematic. The schematic shows 9V from the battery, but I think it is actually around 5V in real life. I am pretty sure I got the voltage and resistance right, but I could have gotten it wrong.

Putting the LED between Q1 and BAT1, how does that change the behavior do you think?

Your edit of the schematic caused the base of Q2 to be shown connected to the negative side of the battery.  Please correct that and show the values of the resistors you are using.

Your circuit is missing some things, there should be a current limiting resistor for the LED and resistors for the bases of the transistors.
As it is now when you push the bottom button the base-emitter junction of Q2 is just acting like a diode and the 9 V supply goes through it and the LED. There's nothing to limit the current so you're lucky the LED didn't burn out.
The next problem is that the LED is in the emitter path of Q2, so it's forward voltage \$V_F\$ gets added to the 0.7 V you need to turn that transistor on. It's better to have the LED between +9 V and the collector of Q1, with a suitable current limiting resistor, something like 470Ω or 1k in series with it.
Then the bases of the transistors need to have some current limiting resistors in series with them, calculate it for 1 or 2 mA of base current.

I added a few changes to the schematic after I realized I forgot to add something into the schematic that is in my actual circuit.

I tried moving the LED in between the collector of Q1 and the battery, but now the LED doesn't light up no matter which buttons I press.

I just found that the LED was on the same path as the button. Now it is working!

If you built the circuit, you should see the LED flash brightly and a puff of magic smoke.
If you redraw the circuit, it becomes clear what is happening. The base/emitter junction of Q2 is a diode with a forward voltage drop of .7 volts. You are applying 8.3 volts to the LED, letting the magic smoke out, and possibly burning out the Q2 base-emitter junction.
Another way to think about it is to add up the series voltage drop of the two diodes. Each diode roughly has .7 volts x 2 = 1.4 volts in parallel with a 9-volt battery. What is wrong with this mental picture? Did you say short circuit?


It is not clear what changes were made to the schematic after some connects and an answer, but the one I see has current limiting for both transistors and the LED.  What is missing are pull-down resistors from each base to GND (the battery - terminal).  This will assure that each transistor remains off whenever its switch is open.  100K is a good value for this.
Also, I would increase R1 to something between 1K and 10K to reduce stress on the transistor base junctions, and increase R2 to something between 330 ohms and 1 K to reduce the LED current to a safe value.
